How to save entity without having to query all relationships
I'm a bit new to Spring Boot and Java. I don't know to handle such cases. I have an entity named venue structure like:
public class Venue {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(nullable = false, updatable = false, columnDefinition = "serial")
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String name;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String city;

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name = "address_id")
    private Address address;

    private String description;

    // getters and setters

}

and venueDTo like this
public class VenueDTO {

    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private String city;
    private String address_id;
    private String description;
}

In the venue service, I want to save the Venue entity without having to query the address and set all fields manually, to get the whole address object to save it with the relationship. I don't know the best practice for doing this
Right now, this is my save function in venueService that runs on a POST request:
public Venue save(VenueDTO venue) {
    Optional<Address> address = addressRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(venue.getAddress_id()));
  
    Venue newVenue = new Venue();
    newVenue.setName(venue.getName());
    newVenue.setCity(venue.getCity());
    newVenue.setAddress(address.get());
    newVenue.setDescription(venue.getDescription());

    return venueRepository.save(newVenue);
}

I don't want to set every field manually like I'm doing with setName, getCity like this.
What is the best practice in Spring Boot to handle such cases?

Use BeanUtils.copyProperties()

I can not understand your problem. Is that related to fetching address from database or set manually the fields?
If you want to get ride of getting address object from database for every insert or update, you can add Long addressId to your entity and just set this property for address and make address field as insertable=false , updatable= false .
for set manually properties you can use modelMapper or mapstruct to convert dto to entity. I can share a example code in new answer

You can use ModelMapper.
This the step by step guild for Model Mapper

add this dependency in pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
    <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
    <version>3.2.2</version>
</dependency>


ModelMapper is a third-party library, so you have to define the bean for ModelMapper.
@Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    return new ModelMapper();
}


You have to use map method of modelmapper in venueService
@Autowired
private ModelMapper modelMapper;

public Venue save(VenueDTO venue) {
    Optional<Address> address = 
    addressRepository.findById(Long.parseLong(venue.getAddress_id()));
    System.out.println(venue.getAddress_id());
    System.out.println(address);

    Venue newVenue = modelMapper.map(venue, Venue.class);
    return venueRepository.save(newVenue);
}



And you're done.

thanks for your help, but this doesn't add the address to the venue

This is the problem of implementing PUT vs. PATCH update endpoints, where PUT means replacing the whole object, while PATCH only replaces existing fields in the object.
Now, this relies on your own implementation. There isn't any "direct" or "pre-defined" way of implementing a PATCH endpoint. One of the ways to do it is the following:

Have a Venue DTO accepted as a @RequestBody and make sure that the id field is not null. If it is null, return an unsuccessful status code. We will call it InputVenue
Get the Venue element with the given id from the database. We will call it StoredVenue.
Set the non-null fields of the InputVenue to the StoredVenue. By doing so, you will have the unmodified data together with the updated fields coming from your input, meaning a complete object to be stored inside the database.
Persist the modified StoredVenue to the database.

This can be also done via Reflection, if you do not want to manually perform all checks on your fields. Take a look over here https://medium.com/@devchopra999/handling-patch-requests-efficiently-in-springboot-3db06e4783e2 for more info.

thanks for your input, but this is a post request not patch, I want to save the venue for the first time, and it has relationship with address

I think you don't want to query Address for saving venue. You can use getReferenceById method instead of findById. It will not create a fetch query for venue and check using foreign key in db, and will throw error if Address is not found, so make sure to handle the error. This getReferenceById method used to be called getOne and getById in old Spring Data versions.
Address address = addressRepository.getReferenceById(Long.parseLong(venue.getAddress_id()));

And for not setting fields manually, you can use the other answer with modelmapper. Other alternatives are objectMapper (already included if you have used Spring Web), or mapStruct.
